# git init --bare on server, add remote, and push in one step

Tags: git

Scenario: I have 15 git repositories in `~/src`.  I have a server with SSH access.  For every repository on my local machine, I want to create a repository on the server, add that new repository as a remote to my local repo, and then finally do an initial push to the new remote.

This had to get done tonight, so this is how I did it (run inside a for loop).  Nevermind that this script is awful and fragile--this is just to show the sort of thing I want to do:

```
server=some_ssh_shortcut
gitdir=git

repo_name=${PWD##*/}

ssh "$server" git init --bare "$gitdir"/"$repo_name".git
git remote add origin "$server":"$gitdir"/"$repo_name".git
git push origin master
```

So, before I write something better for next time, how have *you* done this?  If I write a more robust tool, will I be repeating someone's work hidden in the depths of github that hasn't turned up in my searches?  Is it built in to git but I'm not seeing something?

Comment: i am the author of https://github.com/mnagel/clustergit a tool that allows recursive git commands (like `git status`, `git pull` and `git push`). the creation of remote repos is not yet supported, but it should be quite easy to add the `ssh "$server" git init --bare "$gitdir"/"$repo_name".git`-part and profit from the existing infrastructure.